# nodejs problem sending the variable value to show controller

Tags: javascript, node.js

nodejs problem sending the variable value to show controller

**-- model--**

```
class GloParameter {

    static findGlo(gloFunction, gloCode, gloValue, cb) {
        db.query(findGloParameterFCVActiveQuery, gloFunction, gloCode, gloValue, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                logger.error(err.message);
                cb(err, null);
                return;
            }
            if (res.length) {
                cb(null, res[0]);
                return;
            }
            cb({ kind: "not_found" }, null);
        })
    }

}

module.exports = GloParameter;
```

**-- controller--**

```
exports.serviceX = (req, res) => {

    const xx1 = GloParameter.findGlo(['withdraw_money_time', 'withdraw_money_time', 'start'], (err, data) => {
        console.log('xxxxxxx', data[0].glo_info1)
        return data[0].glo_info1
    })

    res.status(200).send({
        status: 'success',
        data: xx1

    });

    return
}
```

-- db --

```
const findGloParameterFCVActive = `
SELECT * FROM glo_parameter WHERE glo_function = ? AND glo_code = ? AND glo_value = ? AND glo_status = 'active'
`

module.exports = {
    findGloParameterFCVActive
};
```

**Call Api**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXMD6.png)

response API is parameter data : .....

Troubleshooting the display of results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to return a value from an asynchronous callback function, which is not possible in Node.js. The callback function is executed some time after the function in which it was declared has returned, so there is nowhere for the callback function to return to.

To solve this problem, you need to use a different approach, such as using promises or async/await syntax.

For example:

```
/* MODEL */
const { query, findGloParameterFCVActive } = require("./db");
const util = require("util");
const queryAsync = util.promisify(query);

class GloParameter {
  static async findGlo(gloFunction, gloCode, gloValue) {
    try {
      const data = await queryAsync(findGloParameterFCVActiveQuery, [
        gloFunction,
        gloCode,
        gloValue,
      ]);
      if (!data.length) {
        throw { kind: "not_found" };
      }
      return data;
    } catch (err) {
      logger.error(err.message);
      throw err;
    }
  }
}

module.exports = GloParameter;

/* CONTROLLER */
exports.serviceX = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await GloParameter.findGlo(
      "withdraw_money_time",
      "withdraw_money_time",
      "start",
    );
    const xx1 = data[0].glo_info1;
    console.log("xxxxxxx", xx1);
    res.status(200).send({
      status: "success",
      data: xx1,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send({
      status: "error",
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
}
```

Then, I think the problem is that your db.query function does not return a promise, but takes a callback function as the last argument. Therefore, you cannot use await with it, because await only works with promises.
To fix this problem, you need to either wrap your db.query function in a promise and resolve or reject it inside the callback function. For example:

```
/* db File */

const query = (sql, ...params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query(sql, ...params, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(res);
      }
    });
  });
};

const findGloParameterFCVActive = `
  SELECT * FROM glo_parameter WHERE glo_function = ? AND glo_code = ? AND glo_value = ? AND glo_status = 'active'
`;

module.exports = {
  query,
  findGloParameterFCVActive,
};
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Comment: Sorry, please try again.

Comment: Try again, found an error is "not_found"
Verify that the database query found 1 row of data.

Comment: Please console.log(res); after executing query in findGlo of GloParameter. What do you see? If res is an empty array, your error is expected.

Comment: res.length = undefined , But I query the database. with 1 row of data found

Comment: Ok, that means res is not an array, so your query is for getting one row? If so, please remove "not_found" error handler.

Comment: remove "not_found" error handler. The "console.log('res', res)" data value is nothing but "undefined"

Comment: Umm, you mean db.query return undefined? 
Yes.

Comment: Can you show me your db.query function?

Comment: I updated it to the question

Comment: Thank you, I update my answer based on your code.

Comment: After adding the function query ., malfunction No query data is sent.

Comment: Parameters could not be passed, but SQL without parameters works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I updated serviceX function in my answer. please try it

Comment: Error : argument callback must be a function when provided

Comment: I updated my answer. If not, come into above chat room

Comment: Chat room is You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here

Comment: Sorry. please tell me about error

Comment: talk through the program Skype ?

Comment: add is : it.red96@hotmail.com